# How to compare two button values in Android

Tags: android, android-button

First post here so please advise if I do anything wrong :)

I am building an app for college project.

What I have is two buttons in Android Studio. First button creates a random number and the second one I need to compare it to button one and play some audio if they match.

Here is the code for the random number button..

```
public void random(View view) {
int rando = (int) (Math.random()*6);
if(rando == 1){
        play_s.start();
    }else if (rando == 2){
        play_t.start();
    }else if (rando == 3){
        play_p.start();
    }else if (rando == 4){
        play_i.start();
    }else if (rando == 5){
        play_n.start();
    }else {
        play_a.start();
    }
```

and here is the code for the two buttons

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_s"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_s"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:background="@layout/nice_button"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageBtnBack"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="random"
    android:text="Press for letter"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:background="@layout/nice_button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_i"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_i" />
```

So, my question is how can I play some audio if the second button matches the first button??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What determines if the buttons "match"? The text that is displayed on them?

Comment: That's the part I am having difficulty with. How can I get them to match?

button_s should have this 

android:text="s"

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. There are `setText` and `getText` methods for buttons

Comment: Ok, so. When the button3 is pressed the user is asked to select the letter S and when the user selects button_s then audio is played to say correct or fail.

Comment: Okay, so what problems are you having implementing that? Your question only shows a `random` method that looks like it will `start()` some random object.

Comment: what I need to do is have button_s match the random selection that is created in random. So something like

if(rando == 1 && something == "s"){
  success;
}

How could I get "something" to be button_s?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you need a list of all your buttons like `List<Button> allButtons;`, then you can get them later and compare the text displayed on them like so.

```
public void random(View view) {
    Button clicked = (Button) view;
    String clickedTxt = clicked.getText();

    int rando = (int) (Math.random()*6);
    Button randoButton = allButtons.get(rando);

    if(rando == 1 && clickedTxt.equals("s")) {
        play_s.start();
    }

}
```

If you want to compare the button you clicked with the content of the random button, then perhaps you want `TextUtils.equals(clicked.getText(), randoButton.getText())`.